# How to test the controller which have inputs from its dependency using jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Service **userService:**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('kprModule',[]).service('userService', userService);

    function userService() {
        function getUsername(){
            return 'krihsnaChaitanya';
        };
        return{
            getUsername:getUsername
        }
    }
})();
```

Controller **Account.js:**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
    .module('bsp',[])
    .controller('Account', Account);
    function Account(userService) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.title = 'Accounts';
        vm.username = userService.getUsername();
    }
})();
```

**Jasmine test case:**

```
describe('Account', function() { 
  var scope, controller, userServiceMock; 
  beforeEach(module('bsp')); 
  beforeEach(function() {
    userServiceMock = {
      getUsername: function(){} 
    };
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('Account', {
      'userService': userServiceMock
    });
  }));

  describe('testing Title',function(){
    it('checkTitle', function(){
      expect(controller.userService.getUsername()).toEqual('krihsnaChaitanya'); 
    }); 
  }); 
});
```

My question is how to test the `userService.getUsername();` which is assigned to `vm.username` in my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small reformatting of your app just for my own help when working with it. I don't know if it was intentional that you put the service and the controller in different modules but that has the effect of putting them in different angular applications and making them invisible to one another without making one dependent upon the other. In your case, 'bsp' should be dependent upon 'kprModule' and defined as follows:

```
angular.module('bsp',['kprModule']);
```

However, just for simplicity sake I am putting them both in the same module for the example of how to unit test the service within the controller.

```
'use strict';
var kpr = angular.module('kprModule', []);
kpr.service('userService', userService);
function userService() {
    function getUsername() {
        return 'krihsnaChaitanya';
    }

    return {
        getUsername: getUsername
    }
}

kpr.controller('Account', Account);
function Account(userService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.title = 'Accounts';
    vm.username = userService.getUsername();
}
```

To actually test the service you can't mock the service. Or, if you do mock the service then you actually need to make it do the things your test needs, such as implementing the getUsername function within your mock. Since you are actually trying to test the service itself though I removed the mock and injected the actual service into your test so the real thing could be passed into the controller.

Then if we change your test just slightly to look for the username attribute on the controller because the service is never expressly made available on 'vm' we get the following test that does pass:

```
describe('Account', function() {
    var scope, controller, userService;
    beforeEach(module('kprModule'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_userService_) {
        userService = _userService_;
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('Account', {
            'userService': userService
        });
    }));

    describe('testing Title',function(){
        it('checkTitle', function(){
            expect(controller.username).toEqual('krihsnaChaitanya');
        });
    });
});
```

If you have a strong reason to keep the service and controller in separate modules you just have to be sure to 1. make them dependent upon one another and 2. load both in your tests when both are being referenced.